# Azure Resource Health REST API response health status inconsistent with portal result for web app resource type

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

When I send a GET request using the Azure Resource Management REST API to get the resource health status of all the resources under a particular subscription Id like below:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**subscriptionId**/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses?api-version=2015-01-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%3CsubscriptionId%3E/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses?api-version=2015-01-01)

I get the response as below:

```
   {
      "id": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resGrp-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<webAppName>/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current",
      "name": "<webAppName>",
      "type": "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/AvailabilityStatuses",
      "location": "northeurope",
      "properties": {
        "availabilityState": "Unknown",
        "summary": "We are sorry, we are unable to report the health of your Web App",
        "reasonChronicity": "Persistent",
        "recommendedActions": [
          {
            "action": "Continue to monitor this page for updated status",
            "actionUrl": "",
            "actionUrlText": ""
          }
        ],
        "detailedStatus": "No health activity detected on your Azure Web App in past 10 minutes.",
        "occuredTime": "2015-11-18T23:54:59.543Z"
      }
    }
```

As shown above, the Availability State for the particular web app is "**Unknown**".

However, in the Azure portal, this web app has been deliberately paused for more than 15 minutes to check whether the REST API response is consistent with the actual status in the portal, which is expected to return "Stopped" instead of "Unknown".

Does anyone encounter similar behavior or have any idea on this? This result is consistently reproducible with the same unexpected availability status.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this blog to understand what the "unknown" state means.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/reduce-troubleshooting-time-with-azure-resource-health/

You have mentioned your resource was accessed 15 minutes before to pause the web app. Read carefully under the section

> "Signal latency and other important things to keep in mind"

If your resource was not accessed for last 10 minutes then its status becomes unknown.

You can try using the [Azure service management APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check status of your app.

Hope this helps.